# Scribes Editor: no toolbar, statusbar or scrolbars visible

Tags: linux, python, text-editors

I'm planning to give the Scribes text editor a try in everyday usage.

Branching ang compiling the Python code went fine, but when I start it up. I don't see any toolbars or statusbars.

This Iis all I see, when starting the editor:
[image]

Also, when closing the editor, it seems that only the GUI thread is ended, the rest of the programm is still sitting there. when started from the console, I have to stop the process with Ctrl-C manually.

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong, and how to make toolbars and the statusbar appear?